Are questions on specific topolects on topic?
I am thinking about researching some various Chinese topolects (方言).
Are questions on the grammars and vocabularies of Wu, Hakka, Cantonese etc on topic here?

More up to date is What languages count as Chinese?

I honestly don't see why not. There are already such questions on the site, so go ahead. Make sure you tag your question with the relevant tag such as hakka or cantonese.
